# To kill Cicero or not to kill Cicero

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm doing the Dark Brotherhood questline, and now I need to choose either to kill Cicero the jester or let him live. I've been looking up a bit and read that if you kill him you get 500 gold but if you let him live he can be a companion later on.

Now my question: Is this confirmed? And does anyone know if there are any other advantages and disadvantage over killing him or not killing him?

Comment: I just got to this part. If you dont kill him you can just pickpocket him and take the 500 gold.

Comment: It is a fun character to have as a follower for some reasons : He is a little bit more sneaky than the others, so you will be able to backstab ennemies with him at your side. He has very crazy/funny lines in a different circumstances. He won't complain when you trespass.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

He has 500 gold on him as well as his gear. Since you can pickpocket him and receive higher grade gear at the Dawnstar Sanctuary, it is really not lucrative to kill him. If you have completed the quest line for the Dark Brotherhood, and Cicerio is still alive at that point, he will indeed become a Follower.

Leaving him alive thus results in more benefits for you...

Comment: I killed him, cause I AM THE TRUE LISTENER!!!! :P

Answer (score 6):

I just kept him alive because if I really wanted to I could just kill him later anyway. However, I don't know if it changes the storyline at all. When I met Cicero, I chose to help him, but I never got him arrested, so if you didn't help him and he ended up showing at the sanctuary then I don't think it really matters what you do since you still get the same results

You don't get another chance to kill him. After the quest if he's still alive Cicero becomes essential again.